# How to interact with Viewmodel inside recyclerview adapter?

Tags: android, mvvm

I have seen similar question but it did not help me. I would try to be specific about my problem. I have product list in my shopping cart. when I am searching products I want button "Add to cart" disabled for the item which is already present in cart.

Cart item list is inside my view model.

I approached as follows -
When onBindViewHolder is called for a specific position, i need to search if the current item (product) is present in the list of item present in cart, if it is present then disable Button.

Here my problem is that Cart is in Viewmodel and i find myself unable to call viewmodel from OnBindViewholder method.

Is there any better way to do this?

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductAdapter.OurViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    Products currentItem = adapterData.get(i);
    viewHolder.productNamesFragmentItemsBinding.setProductName(currentItem);
    if (currentItem.getPhotoUris() != null) {
    Picasso.get().load(currentItem.getPhotoUris().get(0)).into(viewHolder.productNamesFragmentItemsBinding.ivProductImage);

    //  now i want to search if current item is present in cart (cart is in viewModel), if item
        // is present in cart then disable "Add to Cart" button for current position
        
        //--------------todo : how to do it ??? -----------------------------------
    }
}
```

Comment: Attach your code which you tried.

Comment: I did not write complete code but i have updated, please look into

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize with ViewModelProvider. You can do it inside the constructor for one time initialization like this (Sorry for the naming, I had this code written for a project. I just copy-pasted from there:( )

```
    public class CartChildAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartChildAdapter.CartHolder> {
    
        private ShoppingCartWishListViewModel shoppingCartWishListViewModel;
    
        public CartChildAdapter(Context context) {
            // this is the line you are looking for. Cast context with FragmentActivity
            this.shoppingCartWishListViewModel = new ViewModelProvider((FragmentActivity)context).get(ShoppingCartWishListViewModel.class);
        }
    
     
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CartChildAdapter.CartHolder holder, int position) {
           // call from here
           this.shoppingCartWishListViewModel.getMyProduct(your parameters may be).observe(this,..){
             ......... Your Codes           
}
 }
```

Comment: is this a professional design, or just a workaround? Or a better way to do it? Having viewmodel inside adapter is good practice?.

Comment: Don't know for sure. But we are using this in production. No issue for any users. Didn't face any memory leak issue or something in testing phase. So i think you can use it